# R DT datatable - conditional colour format for continuous value

Tags: jquery, r, datatable, dt

I would like to apply conditional formatting using the `datatable` function in R. Consider the following scenario:

```
test <- data.frame(
  var1 = sapply(1:L, function(x)
    paste("<X>",paste0(x,
                       letters,
                       LETTERS,
                       "\n",
                       collapse=" "))),
  var2 = round(rnorm(L),2)
)

test$var2 <- ifelse(test$var2 > 1, 1, test$var2)
test$var2 <- ifelse(test$var2 < -1, -1, test$var2)
test$tmp  <- test$var2*255
test$R    <- test$G <- 0
test$R    <- ifelse(test$tmp < 0, round(abs(test$tmp)), test$R)
test$G    <- ifelse(test$tmp > 0, round(test$tmp), test$G)
test$col  <- paste0("rgb(",test$R,",",test$G,",0)")

test <- test[,c("var1","var2","col")]

datatable(test)
```

I would like to font colour of `var1` to take values from the `col` variables (which I don't actually need in the final data table).

Is this possible to achieve?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the [DT doc](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

#### 2.9 Escaping table content

You will see that you can put `HTML` content to your table and by using `escape=F`make it readable in `HTML`.

and you can do something like this on the varibles of your dataframe.

```
apply(yourMatrix,2,function(x) ifelse(x>value,  
paste0('<span style="color:red">',x,'</span>'),
paste0('<span style="color:blue">',x,'</span>')
)
```

For example if you have a vector `x <- c(1,2,3,4)` and want value higher than 0 be red you will have

```
[1] "<span style=\"color:red\">1</span>"
[2] "<span style=\"color:red\">2</span>"
[3] "<span style=\"color:red\">3</span>"
[4] "<span style=\"color:red\">4</span>"
```

and then
`datatable(yourMatrix, escape = FALSE)`